# Defining multiple variances of __iter__ in a class

Tags: python, class, iterator

I am writing a game of Connect 4 and have a Grid class that resembles the 2-dimensional grid that the game is played in. The underlying data structure of my Grid class is an instance variable `self.grid` - a 2-dimensional list.

I have overwritten the `__iter__` method as such:

```
def __iter__(self):
    for row in range(self.numRows):
        for col in range(self.numCols):
            yield self.grid[row][col]
```

which I can then call as:

```
for cell in grid:
    # do something with yielded cell
```

At some points, I need to iterate over just a specified row or a specified column. Instead of writing

```
col = 0
for row in range(grid.numRows):
    # do something with grid.grid[row][col]
```

is there any Pythonic, readable way to define a 2nd and 3rd `__iter__` method along the lines of:

```
def __iter__(self, col)
    for row in range(self.numRows):
        yeild self.grid[row][col]
```

which would be called as:

```
for row in grid(col=0):
    # do something with the yielded cell
```

and then the same, but with a specified `row`?

Comment: Have you tried defining two parameters for the __iter__ function, `col` and `row` with default values of `None`. Then you can check if any value have been supplied and yield either the cell, row or column?

Comment: Simply define additional methods for this, e.g. `row` and `column`, that do the necessary iterations, then do `for col in grid.row(3)`.

Comment: I just tried that and I get the same error as when I try to define the second iterator as above - `TypeError: 'Grid' object is not callable`

Comment: @kindall That never crossed my mind, very simple thank you.

Comment: @KOB: Sounds like you're calling the class. You'd need to call `grid.__iter__(...)` directly. Or of course define `__call__` on the class (though that would be unconventional). I still like my solution better, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly have as many of these methods as you like.  You just can't call them all `__iter__()`, because Python does not support method overloading.  You could, for example, do this:

```
def rows(self, col):
    for row in range(self.numRows):
        yield self.grid[row][col]

def cols(self, row):
    for col in range(self.numCols):
        yield self.grid[row][col]

def cells(self):
    for row in range(self.numRows):
        for col in range(self.numCols):
            yield self.grid[row][col]
```

You would then write something like

```
for row in grid.rows(col=0):
    # Do something
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do that, no need to add special methods. Just add iterators, python 3 code below:

```
ALL = 0
ROW = 1
COL = 2

class db:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def __iter__(self):
        return db_iter_all(self.n)

    def __call__(self, what = ALL):
        if what == ALL:
            return db_iter_all(self.n)
        if what == ROW:
            return db_iter_row(self.n)
        if what == COL:
            return db_iter_col(self.n)
        raise ValueError("What what?")

class db_iter_all:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.i = 0
        self.n = n

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.i > self.n:
            raise StopIteration()
        r = self.i
        self.i += 1
        return r

class db_iter_row:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.i = 0
        self.n = n

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.i > self.n:
            raise StopIteration()
        r = self.i
        self.i += 3
        return r

class db_iter_col:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.i = 0
        self.n = n

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.i > self.n:
            raise StopIteration()
        r = self.i
        self.i += 5
        return r
```

And simple example how to use it

```
grid = db(15)
for k in grid:
    print(k)

for k in grid(ROW):
    print(k)

for k in grid(COL):
    print(k)
```